# "Cannot read an empty file" error is eluding me

Tags: python, pypdf

I'm currently trying to resolve an issue and my programming skills aren't quite up to par for it, I believe.

Some context: when converting an excel sheet to a PDF automatically, things labeled as page 1 will sometimes spill over onto the beginning of page 2, which then breaks for the 3rd page (which SHOULD be the second page). This code is an attempt to rectify that for the PDFs I've already identified.

```
for file in oopsarr: #For every file we've identified as it goofing
    pdfFileObj = open(path + "\\" + file, 'w+') #makes the PDF object, lets us read and write
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdfFileObj) #Read it!
    pg1 = pdfReader.pages[0] #Get the pages - a little barbaric, but eh - it works.
    pg2 = pdfReader.pages[1]
    pg3 = pdfReader.pages[2]
    writer = PyPDF2.PdfWriter(pdfFileObj) #writer object
    translatedpage = PageObject.create_blank_page(None, pg2.mediabox.width, pg2.mediabox.height) #Makes a blank page for us to put the stuff on
    pg2.add_transformation(Transformation().scale(sx=1, sy=1).translate(tx=0, ty=-400)) #Transform pg2 to put it onto the new blank page
    translatedpage.merge_page(pg2, False) #Add the new pages to the page object.
    translatedpage.merge_page(pg1, False)
    writer.add_page(translatedpage) #Actually ADD the pages to the PDF
    writer.write(open(path + "\\" + file, 'rb')) #Save it.
    pdfFileObj.close()
```

Whenever I run this code, I get "PyPDF2.errors.EmptyFileError: Cannot read an empty file". After Googling for a couple of minutes, I find out it has something to do with a Canvas - which I am not using. I'm new to this library and was following an old guide with depreciated functions, so that's probably where the issue lies, but I can't quite figure it out on my own.

I've done a bit of Googling, but can't find a good place to start for this, much less even the actual problem I'm trying to solve save a Github page that hasn't been updated in ~7 years and a page referencing a Canvas object which I'm not using.

Comment: `pdfFileObj = open(path + "\\" + file, 'w+')` The "w+" mode erases the existing file contents.  I would think that using the "r" mode makes more sense here.